# My localhost won't work publicly

Tags: windows-7, iis-7

I have IIS7 installed on Windows 7 and `http://localhost/` works fine. I want it to work publicly so I took the following steps:

- went into IIS and enabled directory browsing
- also enabled AnonymousAuthentication in IIS
- then enabled World Wide Web services in my Windows firewall
- used the command promt to find my IPv4 address.

When I access `http://myip:80` on my machine (or any machine connected to my WiFi) it works fine.

When I tried it elsewhere, and on my mobile network, it just won't respond.

Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command prompt IP address most likely is giving you the IP address of your internal network.  You will need your external IP address to view externally.

Additionally, you may also need to set up a rule in your wireless router to route traffic from your external IP address directly to your machine.

For full details, view my answer to a similar question here:
[How can I make my home PC a web server?](https://superuser.com/questions/21931/how-can-i-make-my-home-pc-a-web-server/42260#42260)

Comment: glad to be of some help